# Using xe:applicationLayout any way to do a partial update of of main content area and LeftColumn facet?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Short of placing my xe:applicationLayout inside a panel called panelAll or doing a Full Update, is there any way to do a partial update for my panelMainContent panel and my LeftColumn facet?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xc:DL2_AppLayout>
    <xp:panel id="panelMainContent">
        <xc:xcCustByNameView></xc:xcCustByNameView>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel xp:key="LeftColumn" id="panelLeftColumn">
            <xc:DL2_LeftColumnNav></xc:DL2_LeftColumnNav>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:DL2_AppLayout>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: If the partial refresh of the left column is only meant to set the active menu option, you can also do that with some client side JavaScript. See here for the sample code: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=set-the-active-menu-option-in-an-extension-library-navigator-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refresh the second component in the onComplete of the event that refreshes the first component, as outlined [here](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh).

Comment: P.S. This point is unrelated to this particular question, but remember that panels have slightly more overhead than divs, so unless you're defining data sources / contexts local to the panel, always use xp:div instead.